# On an image click open popup/modal covering the text field

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input box like below which has an icon image after it.

```
<div class="input-div">
   <input type="text" placeholder="DOB">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QoByi9i.png" alt="" class="info">
</div>
```

After the icon is clicked, I want a small popup or modal which opens and covers the entire text field.

How can I do that? [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/efop9r1h/) a fiddle.

With this code, the modal is not coming.

Comment: It should cover the text field?

Comment: Your code is not working because you have not loaded JQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/843d2fn6/

Comment: @hunzaboy the popup/modal's width should be same as the text field. 

This is just a single text field as an example, I have an entire form so It should not cover the entire form, the modal i mean

Comment: Then bootstrap modal will not work for your scenario. It is not designed to work that way. Why don't you check bootstrap popup? or write your own? Is that something you consider?

Comment: I think we can give some width to the modal, can't we? 
I have mentioned popup in the question too.

Comment: @SurajShukla : check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this. Bootstrap Modal is not the solution for your case :)

```js
$(".info").on('click', function() {

  $(".popup-box").toggle();
})
```

```css
.input-div {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.popup-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 87%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
.info {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-div">
  <input type="text" placeholder="DOB">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QoByi9i.png" alt="" class="info">
  <div class="popup-box">Hello! i am a small popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this looks perfect, but I am wondering with that sort of width when there are multiple form field, I might have trouble, let me try and implement this

Comment: You just have to tweak the js code a bit and it will work for all. Let me know what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap Popover instead and tweak css to make it cover your text box.

[popover codepen example](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/zoaBwj)

```
$(function () {
```

$('#pop1').popover()

})

You can use trigger methods to control show/hide or customize popover with close button.